# Problem with success function (javascript) when deploying an spring boot application on tomcat

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring-boot, tomcat

I created a java application with the spring boot framework, when I run it on eclipse no exception or error is triggered. After that, I deployed it on tomcat. until here all is well. but when i try to execute this app on  tomcat, it does not work. The first page is displayed correctly but when I'm trying to connect (login) the 404 error is triggered.

The first step of my application is the login, and here is the part of the code to make this login.

the javascript code :

```
function identification() {
            $("#msgbox").removeClass().addClass('alert alert-info').text('Validating...').fadeIn(1500);
            var login = document.getElementById("login").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
            var tableData = {};
            tableData['login'] = login;
            tableData['password'] = password;
            alert(JSON.stringify(tableData));
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: '/admin/user/LoginTrail/login',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                async: false,
                data: JSON.stringify(tableData),

                success: function (obj) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
                    if(obj.Msg=='OK'){
                        document.location="main.html";
                    }
                },  
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                    alert(JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
                    alert(JSON.stringify(textStatus));
                    console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }
```

and the controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/admin/user/LoginTrail")
public class LoginTrailController {
    private static TreeMap<Integer, LoginTrail> trails = new TreeMap<>();
    public LoginTrailController() {
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/login", produces = "application/json")
    public String login(@RequestBody Map<String, String> args, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String retValue = "OK";
        JsonObjectBuilder builder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
        builder.add("Msg", retValue);
        return builder.build().toString();
    }
```

when I run the application from tomcat, the alert on javascript #alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));  displays a 404 error. And the success part does not execute it passes directly to error ( on javascript). Without going through the conroleur.

I think there is confusion between the jquery and tomcat !

Comment: you need to add port number in ajax call

Comment: Are you not confusing PORTs? I think your springboot app is running on port 8080 and it's not specified anywhere.

Comment: @Vel Pijotrek nope - path is relative to appservers context, you would never use host:port here unless you want to call out to some external system

Comment: how can i add port number in ajax call

Comment: What happens when you test the path /admin/user/LoginTrail/login on Postman / curl? Does it work or does it return 404? Do you have an overall prefix for REST calls? (sometimes code has a prefix like /api before all URLs.

Comment: @fpezzini  how can i test the path on postman

Comment: i solve it by adding to the  url : window.location.pathname + '/admin/user/LoginTrail/login',   #thanks for your help